# MySQL: Loading a txt file with over 1,520,261 records and only 760,131 actually load in

Tags: mysql

As the title says, all my records are not being inserted. this is an issue because  this file will grow exponentially

basically its a .txt file and i am using the following query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\build_filelist.txt'
INTO TABLE buildfinder.find
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(file);
```

It is not your standard load data request as the sql mode has to be set to allow back slashes because the data i am trying to insert is a massive list of files containing backslashes.

my table is pretty simple, just the following:

```
CREATE TABLE find(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
file CHAR(255)
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET= utf8;
```

any suggestions

Comment: Looks like a half of them. When you create a file with, say first 100 records, how many of them gets loaded?

Comment: I know this is unconstructive but surely a file that already has 1.5m records and will grow exponentially IS NOT a good candidate for a load like this into MySQL. Is there a way you can restructure the creation/append of this file to create new files on a more regular basis?  Then you could use techniques that are better equipped as parsing and processing txt files with lots of backslashes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really enough information here to do anything but idle speculation, but:

1. Are you on Windows?   Did the data file orginate in Windows?   You might try the load with the field terminator set to only '\n'
2. What records are getting missed?   Is it possible that the string is longer than the column length?
3. Just  curious why you're using Char(255) instead of Varchar(255).   The filenames will be right-padded, and take more table space than they need to.

Comment: Bloody VARCHAR worked, wouldnt mind but i usually use it for everything without properly understanding the right padding